# Add text dynamically to an input field in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I trying to load text from shared preferences to a text field - I can get the data out fine, The problem I am having is I don't know how to set the input fields to receive values dynamically.  I have not code to show as I don't even know where to start with doing this.  I have searched the internet and have got nowhere.

Could anyone help or guide in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `setText()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String yourText = prefs.getString("your_key", "Empty");
yourEditText.setText(yourText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs for the TextView (EditText extends TextView, so, the code works for both)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29)

Your code should like like something like this

```
String text = "Retrieve this from shared preferences".
TextView textView = findViewById("mytext");
textView.setText(text);
```

You will probably use that on the onCreate of your Activity.

Answer (score -1):

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String yourText = prefs.getString("your_key", "
    EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.yourEditText.setText(yourText);
```

try like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change text in TextView with click a bottun,you can write this:

```
public void ChangeText(){
//ChangeText is metode for onClick the button
TextView Hello=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
//textView is an id for TextView on your window
Hello.setText("Hello world!");
}
```

check this video for better apperception : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rH1xPgD9S0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth sorry i didnt know about them,and this is video,i think its better that he/she watch it until that i write a code for him

Comment: No problem. The best thing to do is to use the "edit" link below your post, to edit the details into your answer. You can keep the link for reference.